# which the effective ranks of embedding matrices in Large LMs?

Tags: large-language-models, embeddings

The hidden size of current LLMs is well in the 8K and above, and I was wondering, has the rank of the embedding matrix, and the rank of the transpose of the output matrix, been increasing with the size, or is it restricted to an smaller subspace, or growing more slowly?

If it were growing more slowly that could mean that the "semantic vector" uses the rest of the hidden size and it could be useful to separate both parts.

Is there some measure or lore knowledge about this?